# Does az ml model deploy --overwrite or az ml service update temporarily put the service into transitioning/ unhealthy state?

Tags: azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service

When we update a webservice endpoint, using `az ml model deploy .... --overwrite` or `az ml service update ...`, does it temporarily go out of service?
Since AKS is managed Kubernetes cluster, does Azure ensure zero down-time by managing pods by updating them to ensure it is always up and running?